# Upload and process a file in django admin

Tags: django, file-upload, django-admin

I have two models, `Course` and `Student`. I want to include a file upload field to the `Course` form in the admin, to accept a CSV file that I will process and store as one or more records in the `Student`s table. My questions are:

1. How can I add this "transient" field to the `Course` model, without it being a column or something in the corresponding table?
2. Where should I do the file processing? I was thinking perhaps overriding the `save_model` method in the `CourseAdmin` class will do it, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - You can override a [form class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L68) in admin. Create you own `ModelForm` and add necessary field there
2 - After that, override [form_save](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L698) or form's `save()` method and process your file there